# How to limit number of connections to server socket

Tags: python

I'm trying to have multiple clients connect to a server socket and transfer data between them, however I want to limit the number of connections that can be made to the server/ number of client processes to 3. How can I do this?

server:

```
import socket
from _thread import *

PORT = 5050
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
ThreadCount = 0
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    tcp.bind(ADDR)
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print("Awaiting connection")
tcp.listen(5)


def threaded_client(connection):
    connection.send(str.encode('Welcome to sv'))
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        reply = 'Server returns: ' + data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        connection.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    connection.close()



while True:
    Client, address = tcp.accept()
    print('Connected to: ' + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1]))
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client, ))
    ThreadCount += 1
    print('Number of threads: ' + str(ThreadCount))
ServerSocket.close()
```

client:

```
import socket

Client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket. SOCK_STREAM)
PORT = 5050
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

print('Awaiting connection')
try:
    Client.connect(ADDR)
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

Response = Client.recv(1024)
while True:
    Input = input('Sends Info: ')
    Client.send(str.encode(Input))
    Response = Client.recv(1024)
    print(Response.decode('utf-8'))

Cliente.close()
```

Comment: socket.listen() specifies the number of unaccepted connections that the system will allow before refusing new connections. use `socket.listen(3)`

Comment: I set it to 5, however I can connect with more than 5 client processes

Comment: if want to limit number of threads might want to Google ThreadPoolExecutor in python3

Comment: You can keep a variable on the server-side which updates the number of connections currently connected to the server and if it exceeds a defined threshold connections simply ignore it. This need also synchronization